# MySQL SUM() returning spurious (?) values

Tags: mysql

Despite spending an hour on this, the solution is eluding me still. I have a complex-ish query that is returning incorrect data for the SUM(). Yet, when I strip it down to the barest form, it outputs the correct data. But **why and fix**, I cannot figure out.

**The Problem**

```
SELECT po.*, SUM( poo.material_qty ) AS total_items_ordered, suppliers.supplier_name
FROM  `purchase_orders` po
LEFT JOIN purchase_orders_items poo ON poo.poid = po.poid
LEFT JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.supplier_id = po.supplier_id
LEFT JOIN materials_batch mb ON mb.purchase_order_no = po.poid
WHERE po_status NOT 
IN (
'Fulfilled',  'Cancelled'
)
AND batch_status NOT 
IN (
'Arrived',  'Cancelled',  'Refused',  'Missing',  'Damaged',  'Completed'
)
GROUP BY po.poid
ORDER BY date_expected ASC
```

Provides wildly incorrect data for 'total_items_ordered'.

```
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+-------------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+--------+----+--------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| poid  | date_raised         | date_expected       | supplier_id | job_id | job_item_id | ref_no | sub_total | VAT     | total    | userid | DN | manual | po_status | total_items_ordered | supplier_name         |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+-------------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+--------+----+--------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| 15571 | 2014-06-24 13:32:55 | 2014-06-25 00:00:00 |           1 |      0 |           0 |        |  14850.10 | 2970.02 | 17820.12 |      1 |    | N      | Raised    |                 545 | John Parker & Son Ltd |
| 15572 | 2014-06-24 13:33:26 | 2014-06-25 00:00:00 |           1 |      0 |           0 |        |    997.80 |  199.56 |  1197.36 |      1 |    | N      | Raised    |                  80 | John Parker & Son Ltd |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+-------------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+--------+----+--------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And yet, when I strip all the complexities out of the query and run the raw SUM(), the value is correct:

```
mysql> SELECT poid, SUM(material_qty) AS total_items_ordered FROM  `purchase_orders_items`  GROUP BY poid;
+-------+---------------------+
| poid  | total_items_ordered |
+-------+---------------------+
| 15571 |                 109 |
| 15572 |                  20 |
+-------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can anyone shed any light on where I'm going wrong here?? I've included all the test table content below just in case you can spot something I've missed. Thank you!

**Data Example**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM purchase_orders;
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+-------------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+--------+----+--------+-----------+
| poid  | date_raised         | date_expected       | supplier_id | job_id | job_item_id | ref_no | sub_total | VAT     | total    | userid | DN | manual | po_status |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+-------------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+--------+----+--------+-----------+
| 15571 | 2014-06-24 13:32:55 | 2014-06-25 00:00:00 |           1 |      0 |           0 |        |  14850.10 | 2970.02 | 17820.12 |      1 |    | N      | Raised    |
| 15572 | 2014-06-24 13:33:26 | 2014-06-25 00:00:00 |           1 |      0 |           0 |        |    997.80 |  199.56 |  1197.36 |      1 |    | N      | Raised    |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+-------------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+--------+----+--------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT * FROM purchase_orders_items;
+--------+-------+-------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| poi_id | poid  | material_id | material_qty | material_price | material_sku | material_name                                    |
+--------+-------+-------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|      1 | 15571 |           2 |            3 |         100.00 | PKS275282    | 406x140 White Universal Beam (S355)              |
|      2 | 15571 |           5 |           10 |          17.40 | 118-64-44    | Test Item (S275)                                 |
|      3 | 15571 |           8 |            1 |        9984.50 | 113-64-21    | A really really really big universal beam (S355) |
|      4 | 15571 |           9 |           77 |          10.00 | 12345        | A thing                                          |
|      5 | 15571 |          10 |           18 |         201.20 | 12-34-56     | 102x230 Narrow Beam (S355)                       |
|      6 | 15572 |           2 |            6 |         100.00 | PKS275282    | 406x140 White Universal Beam (S355)              |
|      7 | 15572 |           5 |            9 |          17.40 | 118-64-44    | Test Item (S275)                                 |
|      8 | 15572 |           9 |            4 |          10.00 | 12345        | A thing                                          |
|      9 | 15572 |          10 |            1 |         201.20 | 12-34-56     | 102x230 Narrow Beam (S355)                       |
+--------+-------+-------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT * FROM suppliers;
+-------------+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
| supplier_id | supplier_name         | supplier_telephone | supplier_fax | supplier_added_date | supplier_added_by | supplier_last_updated | supplier_last_updated_by | supplier_assessed   | supplier_approved_by |
+-------------+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
|           1 | John Parker & Son Ltd | 01227 783333       | 0800 521932  | 2014-05-04 15:57:43 |                 1 | 2014-06-05 16:38:23   |                        1 | 2014-05-04 15:57:43 |                    2 |
|           2 | Superior Glass Ltd.   | 01825 764766       | 01825 767699 | 2014-05-04 17:48:38 |                 1 | 2014-06-04 20:14:16   |                        1 | 2014-05-04 17:48:38 |                    3 |
|           3 | DTS Origins Ltd.      | 01283 3283029      | 01928 303494 | 2014-05-04 17:51:57 |                 1 | 2014-05-04 17:53:08   |                        1 | 2014-05-04 17:51:57 |                    2 |
+-------------+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT * FROM materials_batch;
+-------------------+-------+---------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----+---------+------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| material_batch_id | poiid | rcvd_date           | purchase_order_no | delivery_note_no | qty | rcvd_by | dn_scanned | material_id | supplier_id | batch_status |
+-------------------+-------+---------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----+---------+------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
|                 1 |     1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |             15571 |                  |   3 |       0 | No         |           2 |           1 | Ordered      |
|                 2 |     2 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |             15571 |                  |  10 |       0 | No         |           5 |           1 | Ordered      |
|                 3 |     3 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |             15571 |                  |   1 |       0 | No         |           8 |           1 | Ordered      |
|                 4 |     4 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |             15571 |                  |  77 |       0 | No         |           9 |           1 | Ordered      |
|                 5 |     5 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |             15571 |                  |  18 |       0 | No         |          10 |           1 | Ordered      |
|                 6 |     6 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |             15572 |                  |   6 |       0 | No         |           2 |           1 | Ordered      |
|                 7 |     7 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |             15572 |                  |   9 |       0 | No         |           5 |           1 | Ordered      |
|                 8 |     8 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |             15572 |                  |   4 |       0 | No         |           9 |           1 | Ordered      |
|                 9 |     9 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |             15572 |                  |   1 |       0 | No         |          10 |           1 | Ordered      |
+-------------------+-------+---------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----+---------+------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Comment: my SQL has a extended group by that can return unexpected results.  Either disable the extended group by, or define all non-aggregated fields in your group by. [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) "The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate."  Secondly, your joins may be causing additional records to appear on Purchase Order Items. Do Suppliers or materials batch EVER have more than 1 record per PO? If so, then that too is causing issues.

Comment: you should give sqlfiddle.com link, so people can help you more.

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia Didn't even know sqlfiddle existed ... noted for next time! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the wrong results should be clear when you leave out the `GROUP BY` from your query. For each table you `JOIN`, the number of returned rows is multiplied by the number of rows found by the `JOIN`.

As the `materials_batch` table contains multiple entries per order, the resulting `total_items_ordered` is multiplied by 5 for order number 15571, and its multiplied by 4 for order number 15572.

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
    po.*,
    (
        SELECT SUM(poo.material_qty)
        FROM purchase_orders_items poo
        WHERE poo.poid = po.poid
    ) AS total_items_ordered,
    suppliers.supplier_name
FROM  `purchase_orders` po
LEFT JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.supplier_id = po.supplier_id
LEFT JOIN materials_batch mb ON mb.purchase_order_no = po.poid
WHERE po_status NOT 
IN (
'Fulfilled',  'Cancelled'
)
AND batch_status NOT 
IN (
'Arrived',  'Cancelled',  'Refused',  'Missing',  'Damaged',  'Completed'
)
GROUP BY po.poid
ORDER BY date_expected ASC
```

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. I guess the next question is ... Is there any easy way around this?